# Asp.net Custom RoleProvider with additional function parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

### Background

I have a custom Membership and Role provider for my ASP.net MVC application which works perfectly. A recent requirement however means that I must modify the Role provider to allow for some additional functionality.

Unlike the default provider (one user can have many roles and that's it), my new requirement needs a user to have different collections of roles per company. So for one company a user account might have administrator privileges, but for another company that account might only have standard user privileges... To allow for this, I am replacing the existing usersinrole table with an additional 2 that tie directly into my applications data structure and the existing users table.

Here are the 2 additional tables and how they fit into the schema.

[image: Additional tables]

In principal this does exactly what I need, but I need to modify some of the functions in the Custom Role provider to include a parameter to enable checking of roles of a user **per company**.

Upon trying to make these modification and add the additional parameter I am presented with the following error:

```
'Public Overrides Function IsUserInRole(username As String, rolename As String, [companyID As Integer = 0]) As Boolean' cannot override 'Public MustOverride Function IsUserInRole(username As String, roleName As String) As Boolean' because they differ by optional parameters.
```

### Question

This makes sense as my custom role provider Inherits from the default RoleProvider class, but how do I (if it is at all possible) get around this and pass the Company ID to the required functions?

Answer (score 0):

The doc for [`Overrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k777kzw1.aspx) in the section called **Rules** indicates:

> Matching Signatures.
>
> The signature of this declaration must exactly match the signature of
>   the property or procedure that it overrides. This means the parameter
>   lists must have the same number of parameters, in the same order, with
>   the same data types. In addition to the signature, the overriding
>   declaration must also exactly match the following:
>
> - The access level
> - The return type, if any

This rigidity probably means that you will have to code a method with an alternate name (perhaps `IsUserInRoleForCompany`) and then refactor your code to call that method rather than `IsUserInRole`.  Not ideal but you would have had to refactor every call anyway to add the new parameter.

As an alternative you might consider caching the current user's CompanyID in a manner that allows you to retrieve that value from cache (or cookie or whatever) and then use it within the `IsUserInRole` -- negating your need to pass it as a parameter, and thus getting around the rigidity problem.

Hope that helps.